# More Detailed Error From createFileAtPath?

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway to get more detailed error data back from "createFileAtPath" I was kind of expecting an NSError? Currently I am using the BOOL return value.

```
success = [fileMan createFileAtPath:fileOnDisk contents:dBuffer attributes:nil];
if(success == YES) NSLog(@"FileCreated");
else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Failed to create file");
    return 1;
}
```

gary

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I agree... I'd love to have a function for this that accepts NSError!

Errors returned in this case are usually one of the POSIX errors declared in `errno.h` (`errno` is automatically included for you as part of the Cocoa or Foundation headers).

To see the error, use the `strerror` function from `errno.h` and reference the global `errno` integer, which is set by the low-level POSIX io functions when a problem occurs:

```
if (![fm createFileAtPath:@"/etc/foobar.txt" contents:data attributes:nil]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error was code: %d - message: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
}

// output will be: Error was code: 13 - message: Permission denied
```

The list of error code constants are listed in the in the [Error Handling Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH202-SW2) (in addition to the errno.h header itself).

Comment: This answer is huge. Clever!

Answer (score 11):

You're not supposed to use that method; they forgot to put this in the main docs (!), but if you read the Apple header file you find this comment:

> /* These methods are provided here for compatibility. The corresponding
>   methods on NSData which return NSErrors should be regarded as the
>   primary method of creating a file from an NSData or retrieving the
>   contents of a file as an NSData.  */

So, instead, Apple expects you to use this (which, from testing, appears to function exactly the same - except that it's located in a bizarre class where you'd never think to look for it (I want to create an empty file ... so I have to ... instantiate a nil NSData object? What?) it has an NSError object):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:options:error: